# Elasticsearch assigning primary and replica nodes for indices

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, cluster-computing, distributed-computing

I have setup an Elasticsearch cluster with 1 master, 1 client and 2 data nodes. The client and the 2 data nodes are in one machine and the master is on a separate machine.
The IPs are as follows:

```
192.168.1.3 - master
192.168.1.2:9201 - client
192.168.1.2:9200 - data1
192.168.1.2:9202 - data2
```

I have data belonging to two indices (`movie-ame` and `movie-eur`) and want to keep the data in the nodes as shown below. Using logstash I imported data into data nodes.

**movie-ame**

```
primary shards in data1
1 replica in data2
```

**logstash.conf**

```
input {  
  file {
    path => "C:\Users\azinneera\Desktop\logstash-5.1.1\bin\data.csv"
    start_position => "beginning"    
  }
}

filter {  
  csv {
      separator => ","
      columns => ["ID","MovieName","ReleaseYear","Country","Genres"]
  }
}

output {  
    elasticsearch {
        action => "index"
        hosts => ["192.168.1.2:9200"] 
        index => "movie-ame"
    }
    stdout {codec => rubydebug}
}
```

**movie-eur**

```
primary shards in data2
1 replica in data1
```

**logstash.conf**

```
input {  
  file {
    path => "C:\Users\azinneera\Desktop\logstash-5.1.1\bin\movieeur.csv"
    start_position => "beginning"    
  }
}

filter {  
  csv {
      separator => ","
      columns => ["ID","MovieName","ReleaseYear","Country","Genres"]
  }
}

output {  
    elasticsearch {
        action => "index"
        hosts => ["192.168.1.2:9202"] 
        index => "movie-eur"
    }
    stdout {codec => rubydebug}
}
```

But it seems that data1 acts as primary for both indices and the replicas for both indices are in data2.

**This is what the cluster state shows**
[image]
[image]

Comment: And what's the problem?

Comment: As I have mentioned in the question, data2 should act as primary for index movie-eur and data1 should hold the replica. Looking at the cluster state, it seems this has not happened. Rather data1 is being primary for both indices. The node id of both indices are the same.

Comment: Ok, I see what you mean, but I don't see how it's a problem. The difference between replica and primary is that the primary is currently in use and the replica is not. When/if the primary is not available, the replica will be used.

Comment: Yes but I want to balance the load between the two nodes. This way all the queries will directed to data1

Comment: Ok. To do it, I would use the kopf elasticsearch plugin. Set the number of replica of movie-eur to 0. The cluster will delete the replica and rebalance the shards. If it does not, you can move the shards manually. Once the primary are where you want them, reset the number of replica to 1, the replica will be created on the other node. This operations can be done in the kopf ES plugin.

Comment: Works fine, but not exactly the way you mentioned. The shards were rebalanced with each node containing 3 primary shards of one index and 2 replicas of the other. However, this is ok to go ahead with. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is nothing wrong.  Elasticsearch will put the primary/replica on different nodes and keeps them in sync on a per shard basis.

When you query data out of Elasticsearch, it will query from either the primary or one of the replicas (because they are considered identical copies).  Overall, Elasticsearch will handle the load balancing and you don't have to worry about it.

If you really do want to worry about it, there are some [settings](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/shards-allocation.html) that you can tweak.